# vue-router beforeRouteUpdate uses old parameter when switching

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I'm using vue-router and trying to link from one user record to another, pretty simple.

My route is boilerplate from vue-router docs:

```
  { path: '/user/:user_id', name: 'user', component: User, props: true },
```

I'm linking with the following code:

```
<a @click="selectUser(user.parent)">{{user.parent.email}}</a>
```

The method:

```
  selectUser(user) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'user', params: { user_id: user.id } })
  },
```

I'm attempting to use beforeRouteUpdate to load up the changed user:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  alert(this.user_id)
  this.fetch()
  next()
},
```

And my fetch method:

```
  fetch() {
    this.$store.dispatch('users/fetchUser', this.user_id)
  },
```

I'm using vuex as well. The alert of the this.user_id (prop) in the beforeRouteUpdate responds with the original id, not the changed one. Shouldn't it be the newly changed/passed ID? The url changes to the new id, but it simply loads data with the old/original ID rather than the newly passed one.

Comment: where is the declaration of this.user_id?

Comment: You need to use `to.params.user_id` to get the changed user, and then assign it to `this.user_id` before accessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `to.params` to access route params. You need to assign values on your component. They don't get assigned automatically.

In your case, you need to assign `to.params.user_id` to `this.user_id` before calling `this.fetch()` in `beforeRouteUpdate`.

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  this.user_id = to.params.user_id
  alert(this.user_id)
  this.fetch()
  next()
}
```

Refer to [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) about in-component navigation guards.

Comment: I marked this as the answer and it seems to work but I'm getting the error: [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "user_id"

Comment: Does `user_id` need to a prop on your component, can it not be an item on `data`?

Comment: Yes it does, otherwise I can't link directly /task/5 for example - I would have to traverse from a selected list of tasks, correct?

Comment: Per the documentation - I needed to use a local variable which copies the prop. Then my beforeRouteUpdate updates that value instead of attempting to manipulate the prop. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a watch on the prop `user_id`, when it changed you can execute the method `fetch()`

In your case:

```
watch: {
    user_id: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.fetch();
    }
},
```

I hope this can be a useful!